# Display queue message in div

Tags: javascript, foreach, queue

I have a array of string and i want to display on stage this strings in div:

```
var $div = $('#myDiv');
var messages = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

messages.forEach(function (m) {
  setTimeout($div.text(m), 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     var $div = $('#myDiv');
    var messages = ['first', 'second', 'third'];


        var t=1;

        var timer=setInterval(function()
        {

            $('#myDiv').text(messages[t]);
            t++;
            if(t==messages.length)
            {
                window.clearInterval(timer)
            }
        },2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you want it changed every second.

With  your current implementation, it will loop over the messages (quickly) and then set the text 1 second from now.

What you need to do is increase the timeout for each subsequent message update:

```
var i = 0;
messages.forEach(function (m) {
  setTimeout(function() {$div.text(m)}, i * 1000);
  i++;
});
```